# ASP.NET Identity - RedirectLocation is null inside Application_EndRequest

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, owin

I created a brand new ASP.NET MVC project with Identity Authentication.

The autogenerated `Startup.Auth.cs` has the following code:

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
    app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
    app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
    app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationSignInManager>(ApplicationSignInManager.Create);

    app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
    {
        AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
        LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
        Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
        {
            OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
                validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
        }
    });
// ......
```

The important part above is the `LoginPath` which is set to **/Account/Login** (which is the default).

When I try to access a page/action with the `[Authorize]` attribute without being logged in, I'm redirected to that login page, as exptected.

In my `Global.asax.cs` file, I put the following code:

```
protected void Application_EndRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var subnet = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SubnetForWindowsAuthentication"].ToString().Split(';');
    if (this.Response.StatusCode == 302
        && this.Response.RedirectLocation.Contains("/Account/Login") 
        && subnet.Any(ip => this.Request.UserHostAddress.Contains(ip))
        && this.Request.Browser.Win32)
    {
        this.Response.StatusCode = 401; // ask the browser to negotiate an identity
        this.Response.SuppressFormsAuthenticationRedirect = true;
    }
}
```

When the user is being redirected, the `StatusCode` is 302. Now, I need to check if the user is being redirected to the login page. The problem is `this.Response.RedirectLocation` is `null`, even though the response status code is 302.

Why is `this.Response.RedirectLocatio` null?

### Further Details

The funny thing is that `this.Response.Headers["location"]` has the URL I'm being redirected to (which should be `this.Response.RedirectLocation` as well). I could use the header directly to check if the URL contains **/Account/Login**, but when I change `this.Response.StatusCode` to 401, which should challenge the browser to negotiate a windows authentication identity, for example, but instead it just fails showing an IIS error page displaying: **HTTP Error 401.0 - Unauthorized**.

I'm trying to achieve the solution proposed [in this link](https://world.episerver.com/blogs/Dan-Matthews/Dates/2014/8/Mixing-Forms-and-Windows-Authentication/), but instead of using Forms Authentication, I'm using ASP.NET Identity.

Comment: `Response.RedirectLocation` has value when you have response code 301. When you change status code to 401 browser doesn't challenge anything. Whether to show login page or Windows authentication dialogue depends on the identity provider. Here in this case you are suppressing that. You need to enable Windows authentication on your application and disable forms authentication to see Windows login dialog.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya thank you. My idea is to allow users in my local network to use windows authentication, that's why I manually force the response status code to 401. Otherwise, the user will just be redirected to the login page, and fill username and password. It seems inserting `<authentication mode="Windows">` made the 401 status code trick work, but I'm still not sure why would `RedirectLocation` contain the login page URL only for 301 and not 302.